# Filter text/tweet column with keywords

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I downloaded a timeline and have now a dataframe with 3200 observations of 1 variable (tweets). I want to filter my dataframe using certain keywords but don't get the expected results. Any help is most appreciated.

I tried this function, for example

```
filter(data.frame, grepl('keyword',text))
```

and I get one tweet matching my keyword but I know that there are more.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of what you mean by "don't get the expected results"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
data<-read.csv("yourdata.csv")
filter <- grep("keyword1|keyword2|keyword3", data$text, ignore.case=TRUE)
Tweets_filtered <- data[filter,]
```